# Standardised set of props passed React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, var, react-props

Is it possible to create a standardised set of props in a variable and pass them to multiple children? The idea is to create a var that contains both prop names and values and then add it to individual  elements.

```
render(){

    var generalComponenentProps = {
        status:{this.state.statusLast},
        lastPageStatus:{this.state.status},
        LastPageTitle:{this.state.title},
    }

    return (

        <PreAuthsPage generalComponenentProps />

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an object as props by spreading it:

```
<PreAuthsPage {...generalComponentProps} />
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that you probably don't want curly braces around each of the values in your example `generalComponentProps` - you probably want `status: this.state.statusLast` etc.

Comment: Perfect Thanks, Quick Question though, what is the basis behind the ... of {...generalComponentProps}. Is this for ease of understanding or does ... actually mean something. If the latter, I am unaware, please tell me.

Comment: the `...` means "spread" or "rest" - in general it makes a shallow copy of the target object or array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax